# Ruby: better way to return several methods as procs from a module

Tags: ruby

It's pretty easy to return a method like a proc from a module:

```
module Foo
  def self.bar
    # Method implementation
  end

  def self.baz
    # Method implementation
  end

  def self.qux
    # Method implemenatation
  end

  def self.zoo
    # Method implementation
  end
end

Foo.method(:bar) # Returns a proc object
```

But what if I want to return *more than one* (but not all of them) method from the same module?
One way to do that is:`[:bar,:baz].inject([]) {|memo,i| memo << Foo.method(i)}`

Is there a better, more agile way to do the same?

Comment: Won't `%[bar baz].map{|sym| Foo.method(sym)}` work?

Comment: If that is not what you want, then your question is not clear.

Comment: What do you mean by agile?

Comment: I mean do the same with a less amount of code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use monkey patching to make it look however you wish:

```
class Object
  def get_methods(*methods)
    methods.map { |m| method(m) } 
  end
end


module Foo
  def self.bar
    # Method implementation
  end

  def self.baz
    # Method implementation
  end
end

Foo.get_methods(:foo, :baz)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Foo.methods(false).map {|e| Foo.method(e)}
```

`Foo.methods(false)` will return all class methods that are **not** inherited as an array and `map` will iterate over each element.

**EDIT**

After taking into account the comments below:

```
proc_arr = [:bar, :baz].map {|e| Foo.method(e)}
```

Comment: Sorry, my question was a bit unclear, I've updated it. I'm looking for a way to return specific methods, not all of them.

Comment: @DreamWalker do you know in advance which methods do you need or they'll be determined at run-time?

Comment: ok, in that case just replace `Foo.methods(false)` with an array of the names of your methods. If you want to modify the initial array itself use `map!` instead of just `map`. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a better way, but maybe this is a bit cleaner than your solution:

```
proc_methods = []
# => [] 
(Foo.methods - Object.methods).each { |m| proc_methods << Foo.method(m) }
# => [:bar, :baz] 
proc_methods
# => [#<Method: Foo.bar>, #<Method: Foo.baz>]
```

`Foo` inherits its methods from `Object` class, that is the default root of all Ruby objects. (http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Object.html)

With `Foo.methods - Object.methods` you keep only your custom methods.